# Authenticity of the hadith about whoever recites ten verses of Surat al-Baqarah in the morning

Tags: hadith, source-identification

Sayyiduna 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ud (radiyallahu’anhu) said:

> Whoever recites the following ten verses of Surah Baqarah in the morning:
>
> (1) will be saved from Shaytan till the evening, and whoever recites it in the evening will be protected from Shaytan till the morning.
>
> (2) Furthermore, he will not experience unpleasant surprises in his family or wealth.
>
> (3) If these verses are recited on an insane person, he will be cured.
>
> (Sunan Darimi, Hadith: 3382 & Shu'abul Iman, Hadith: 2412)

**Question:** Is this hadith authentic? What is the grade of it?

Answer (score 3):

The hadith you are referring to is narrated by 'Aasim through Al-Sha'bi through 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ood. Al-Sha'bi did not meet 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ood, so the chain of narration is severed, and the hadith is weak.

The hadith is quoted in multiple books as:

> :روينا من طريق الشعبي أنه قال: قال عبد الله بن مسعود
>
> > من قرأ عشر آيات من سورة البقرة في ليلة لم يدخل ذلك البيت شيطان تلك الليلة، أربع من أولها، وآية الكرسي، وآيتان بعدها، وثلاث آيات من آخرها
>
> :وفي رواية
>
> > لم يقربه ولا أهله يومئذٍ شيطان، ولا شيء يكرهه، ولا يقرؤه على مجنون إلا أفاق
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> We were told through Al-Sha'bi that 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ood said:
>
> > Whoever recites the following ten verses of Surat al-Baqarah at night, the shaitan will not enter his house that night: the first four verses, the verse of al-Kursi and the two verses after it, and the last three verses.
>
> In another narration:
>
> > No shaitan will approach him or his family that night, nor anything that he hates; and if recited to an insane person, that person will be cured.

First, the hadith is mawqūf on 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ood, i.e., it is not attributed to the Prophet ﷺ.

Second, Al-Sha'bi is ['Aāmir ibn Shuraḣīl ibn 'Abd](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=563&bk_no=60&flag=1), who did not narrate through 'Abdullah ibn Ma'ood.

Therefore, the hadith is *mursal* (severed chain), i.e., weak.

Comment: ok. thank you for your response. Can you mention any authentic duas mentioned in authentic hadith that I can read for protection of my family members who are traveling abroad?? So that I do not have to worry about them. thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Kilise Sorry, yes. I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @AAP Please post this request as a new question.